# Does a hero suffer wounds from new minions as Darkness Spreads?

Tags: defenders-of-the-realm

In the Defenders of the Realm rulebook, the *Suffering Wounds* section (p. 7) says

> If a hero ends a turn in a location with enemy minions, the he suffers a wound for each minion at that location.

On first reading, I thought that meant that once a hero's actions were spent, they would suffer a wound for each minion present on their location. But, a player's turn is divided up into three segments (p. 5): Daytime(hero actions), Evening(draw cards), and Night(darkness spreads) and new minions are placed during Night.

Does a hero suffer wounds if minions were placed on their location during the Night as darkness spreads?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question has been asked before. Luckily, the designer has clarified the [answer](http://boardgamegeek.com/article/5415183#5415183). You suffer wounds at *the end* of your heroic actions when minions are in your location, not during the Night when new minions are placed.

> Wounds are suffered at the end of your actions - the end of the Daytime Phase of play and prior to drawing Darkness Spreads cards. If Minions appear on your location by a Darkness Spreads card, you do not suffer wounds to them.

You will also note that the rules regarding wounds suffered in this manner are covered within the Daytime section of the rule book, and not near the end of the rule book covering Night.

Comment: Thanks! I got caught up in the definition of a 'turn'. Apparently, it is also appears in the DotR [FAQ](http://boardgamegeek.com/filepage/58401/defenders-of-the-realm-faq) on p. 11, though I couldn't find it when I was looking for it the first time.